# Does Selenium click work with labels?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML snippet:

```
<label id="on" class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>
```

My code snippet:

```
onBtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cb-enable")
onBtn.click()
```

Also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label#on.cb-enable").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.cb-enable').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("on").click()
```

I checked over the element properties:

```
.id = {0b236cc6-c0b9-4592-a171-96d2c8890880}
.is_enabled() = True
.is_displayed() = True
.size = {'width': 36, 'height': 30}
```

No error is thrown, but the label is not switching from `Off` to `On` as it is supposed to. This label triggers a Javascript action, and that's what I really need to execute.

Also `len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cb-enable"))` = 1

I've used Selenium plenty of times, but not since a few weeks back.

Update: I got it working, by maximizing the window manually when it ran. I think the button was partially hiding under the bottom popup bar on the website.

Comment: Are you sure that this particular element triggers the action you expect? Could you share the link to the web-site, or provide a source code of the page? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the span with `On` text there.

Comment: Oops, it logged me out. Updated download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho0l0i43atte8wx/source.htm?dl=0

Comment: Can you please give a snapshot of the webpage or at least that button?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyf48ju1f0jzec8/2014-11-19_005659.png?dl=0

Comment: @User thank you for the update. According to the page source, the click on `label` with `id="on"` is handled by the jquery onclick event, try: `driver.find_element_by_id('on').click()`.

Comment: @User and, just in case, try waiting for the element to be clickable: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'on'))).click()`, where `EC` is imported via `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`.

Comment: I updated question with 3 other attempts and some properties of the found element.

Comment: try with XPATH: //div[@class='col2_wrap']//label[span='On']

Comment: I got it working, by maximizing the window manually when it ran. I think the button was partially hiding under the bottom popup bar on the website.

Comment: So, the only thing you have to add now is `driver.maximize_window()` for maximizing the window.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that, but going to switch to headless browser PhantomJS now that I see everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can use Selenium execute javascript code like:

`driver.execute_script(javascript_code)`

to click element of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.cb-enable').click()
```

Comment: No, that does not work. I tried a few different selection methods. Also by `id` too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

Inlcude a wait for the webElement to appear

onBtn.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'`

Comment: Secondly, I don't think a wait will work since it is already finding the element fine? As you can see in the OP, len() = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on `span` inside the `label` via Xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='cb-enable'][@id='on']/span[text()='On']").click()
```

or via CSS:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[class='cb-enable'][id='on'] span").click()
```